# Is it possible to create multiple events in a single go?

Tags: 2007, calendar

I have a calendar list on SharePoint, and I wanted to find out, can I create a multiple Calendar events, on different times based on the time I entered for the first event?

For example:

1. I enter an event on 01/01/2012
2. Automatic events are create 8 months later, on 01/08/2012 (or whatever +240 days is), and 16 months later.

These should be the original event names, only prefixed (i.e. the first event is called "John Doe", the second should be called "8 Mo - John Doe", the third is "16 Mo - John Doe".

Is any of these possible at all? Or am I barking entirely at the wrong tree?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a workflow in SharePoint Designer and attach it to the Item Added event. In the workflow, create your additional events

Comment: How can I do that? Creating events in a workflow?

Comment: Now that I think of it, I don't think I have access to SharePoint Designer (it's a specialized intranet, no internet access etc). Is there any way to do it without it?

Comment: Not really, as you need some kind of programmable solution, SharePoint Designer is the easiest option. Of course, if you can develop and deploy custom event receivers, you can go in that direction as well

Comment: Basically you would create a WF in SPD that creates additional items in the list when an item is created.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by creating Custom Timer Job.. Here is link to create Timer Job..

http://adicodes.com/timer-job-in-sharepoint-for-specific-site/

Comment: if it satisfy your requirement then don't forget to mark as answer..

Comment: I don't see how this will really help - can you elaborate?